# Delphi Master-Detail grid components

Tags: delphi, components, grid, master-detail

What other components are there to produce Master-Detail grids, like what [InfoPower](http://www.woll2woll.com/infopower/WhatsNewIn4000.htm) can do (where the detail grid is in the master grid - first image in the in InfoPower link)?

Answer (score 6):

The one and only: [ExpressQuantumGrid](http://www.devexpress.com/products/vcl/exquantumgrid/).

Of course there are many alternatives, but don't struggle with the half-baked.

Answer (score 1):

[QuantumGrid](http://www.devexpress.com/products/vcl/exquantumgrid/) is nice but also very heavy and quite expensive. [TDBGridEh](http://www.ehlib.com/) seems to be a good alternative. Also [TVirtualStringTree](http://code.google.com/p/virtual-treeview/) can be used as a grid but this requires much more effort to implement.

Answer (score 0):

You can do that with any DB-aware grids and ClientDataSets linked in a master-detail relationship.  [This docwiki page](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/en/Making_the_Table_a_Detail_of_Another_Dataset) is a good place to start looking for info on how that's done.

Comment: I think the OP is asking for grids capable of showing master-detail data inside the same grid (like infopower, orpheus, DevExpress, etc)